# LSTM using previously predicted data to attain new values converges

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to compare the output of an LSTM to my baseline data of an assets price `t+100` into the future using a rolling frame, for example:

I take 5 consecutive price points, from date n1 to n5, I predict n6, and push n6 into the LSTM input data and remove n1 and repeat over until I have exausted my data making sure that each time I remove n1, I store this in a 'tracking' list to compare against my known data `t+100` into the future. The idea is to keep predicting values using 5 previsouly predicted data points.

What I have noticed is that very quickly my predicted n6 values start to converge to a single value, almost straight away, see fig below:

[image]

My current configuration for the LSTM looks like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='swish', input_shape=(5, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation = 'swish'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics = 'mse')
model.fit(X,y,epochs=100)
```

When I run the model against a rolling 5 point timeframe of the test data plotting the predicted values, I get a very accurate match to the test data set which suggests my model is okay.

[image]

I was expecting some arbitraty values to come out of predicting price points between `t` and `t+100` but as for why it converges in figure 1 I am not entirely sure, is this an expected outcome of using predicted data over and over to predict more data?

Edit:
Here is an example of payload data showing the shifting values with time:

```
[[[0.86381593]
  [0.81616699]
  [0.82052763]
  [0.81930565]
  [0.82811061]]]
round: 1
[[[0.81616699]
  [0.82052763]
  [0.81930565]
  [0.82811061]
  [0.81889451]]]
round: 2
[[[0.82052763]
  [0.81930565]
  [0.82811061]
  [0.81889451]
  [0.81397408]]]
round: 3
[[[0.81930565]
  [0.82811061]
  [0.81889451]
  [0.81397408]
  [0.80748832]]]
round: 4
[[[0.82811061]
  [0.81889451]
  [0.81397408]
  [0.80748832]
  [0.79987484]]]
round: 5
[[[0.81889451]
  [0.81397408]
  [0.80748832]
  [0.79987484]
  [0.79139411]]]
round: 6
[[[0.81397408]
  [0.80748832]
  [0.79987484]
  [0.79139411]
  [0.7828725 ]]]
round: 7
[[[0.80748832]
  [0.79987484]
  [0.79139411]
  [0.7828725 ]
  [0.77399129]]]
round: 8
[[[0.79987484]
  [0.79139411]
  [0.7828725 ]
  [0.77399129]
  [0.76494324]]]
round: 9
[[[0.79139411]
  [0.7828725 ]
  [0.77399129]
  [0.76494324]
  [0.75581664]]]
round: 10
[[[0.7828725 ]
  [0.77399129]
  [0.76494324]
  [0.75581664]
  [0.74665457]]]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using (t2, t3,...,t6) to predict t7 and not (t6, t2, t3,...,t5) when you continue forecasting using the predicted values? In other words, are you constructing the correct sequence?

Comment: yup, added a snipped of each cycle to the question just now

Comment: Ive even just tried changing the first 50 data points with actual test values, then suddenly switch over to predicted values only and it still shows the same converging pattern. as soon as the test values run out.